# FirebaseListAdapter not firing populateView()

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebaseui

After finding some people saying that `FirebaseRecyclerAdapters` are broken inside of fragments (and trying for about 4 hours to get it to work before that), I decided to switch to a `FirebaseListAdapter`, as I found examples of that working inside of fragments. However, I'm having issues. The `populateView()` method never seems to be firing and I'm getting no errors. Here is my code for the fragment:

```
public class PasteFromFirebasePopup extends DialogFragment implements AdapterView.OnClickListener {
Activity activity;

private FirebaseListAdapter mFirebaseAdapter;
private DatabaseReference mClipboardHistoryReference;
private ListView mListView;

public PasteFromFirebasePopup() {}

@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                                   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.clip_history_popup_list, container, false);

    mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.clipboardHistoryListView);

    activity = getActivity();
    mClipboardHistoryReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.FIREBASE_CHILD_CLIPBOARD_HISTORY);
    Log.d("clipboardRef", mClipboardHistoryReference.toString());

    mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<FirebaseString>
            (activity, FirebaseString.class, R.layout.clip_history_popup_item, mClipboardHistoryReference) {
            TextView mTextView;

        @Override protected void populateView(View v, FirebaseString model, int position) {

            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.clipboardHistoryTextView);
            Log.d("model text", model.getText());
            mTextView.setText(model.getText());
        }
    };

    mListView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);

    return rootView;
}

@Override public void onClick(View v) {}

@Override public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mFirebaseAdapter.cleanup();
}

}
```

No matter what I try, the log inside of `populateView()` absolutely never fires. I have triple checked my reference, and there is indeed something in there (only one item at the moment, but as far as I can tell that shouldn't matter). Am I missing something? Does this not work inside of `DialogFragments`? If not, does anyone have a suggestion for a `popup` that can hold a `FirebaseListAdapter/RecyclerAdapter` successfully?

Any help is duly appreciated.

EDIT: my `build.gradle (app)` , as I think this may have something to do with it.

```
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
compile 'com.github.smart-fun:XmlToJson:1.2.2'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'

testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.0'

compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6'
annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.6'

compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: The most common cause is that either there's no data at the location you attach to, or that you don't have permission to read that data. If it's the latter case, there should be a warning about it in the logcat output.

Comment: I would agree, but I'm able to see the data there, and through a similar call (but not using an adapter, just setting some text) am able to access other data in the database.

Comment: Hmm. I was able to get it to work finally, after deleting all the nodes inside my database and then re-adding them. I have no idea why this worked....

Comment: Good to hear that you got it sorted!